# apex : convert object to a list

Tags: apex, list, object

I have an object with value `(s1,s2,s3,s4)` (this is the value I get during `System.debug`).
Now I want to convert this values to list of strings, i.e `['s1','s2','s3','s4']`.

How can I do that?

I tried,

```
List<String> test = new List<String>();
test.addAll((List<String>)obj); // threw an error cant convert List<Any> to List<String>
```

```
List<String> test = new List<String>();
test.addAll((List<String>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(obj.toString())); 
// throws Unexpected character ('(' (code 40)): expected a valid value (number, String,  array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at input location [1,2]
```

---

**EDIT:**
In case you are wondering how I got the object.
The object is a list of strings I retrieved from the body during an API call, after converting to `Map<String, Object>` I get the above obj

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately apex doesn't handle list-level type conversion so if "obj" is a `List<Object>` and even if each `Object` is actually a `String` you still cannot convert that list directly to a `List<String>` via type casting.

You have two options. First is to do a loop:

```
List<Object> obj = ...;
List<String> objAsStrings = new List<String>();

for (Object value : obj) {
  objAsStrings.add((String) value);
}
```

Or you can try serializing and deserializing via JSON:

```
objAsStrings = (List<String>) JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(obj), List<String>.class);
```

Both will fail if not all entries in the `obj` are strings (the JSON approach will be more permissive, only failing with numeric and Boolean entries, since many other types are still expressed as string-like in JSON).

Both are relatively expensive, CPU wise, but the JSON approach costs more CPU time for smaller arrays. It wins when you get to large arrays.

Comment: the 2nd option worked , thanks also object is not list of Object (as that would be easy)[for the first approach] , it's simply a object.

Comment: Since this is working, "obj" must actually be a `List<Object>`. You can check by simply trying to cast: `(List<Object>) obj` and see if you get an exception.

Comment: See the JSON untyped deserialization documentation for detail.

Comment: yes , it's `List<Object>`  but when i try `for(Object o : obj)` i get  `for should iterate over a collection` maybe i should type cast first and then try?

Comment: Just do `for (Object value : (List<Object>) obj)` instead.